# Issue for Running PHP project using eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I am using eclipse Indigo to work on java.Now i get one PHP project to run.So, i seached the net and install PDT using eclipse help-->install new software.Then i imported that project and tried to run but is it showing "**Cannot connect to destination (localhost)"**.So, as far as i am getting from this error that i have to install a server.Is it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need local webserver with PHP enabled.I would suggest ZendServer CE, it has built-in ZendDebugger PHP module, which helps you a lot.It free (registartion required).

Answer (score 3):

if you are new to php i would recommend to install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) server for running php which is bundled with Mysql and phpmyadmin.here is download link http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/latest/download